# Удалёный вход в систему с разных компьютеров

Tags: windows, сервер

Если я логинюсь с разных компов (удалённый рабочий стол) под одним именем дисковые ресурсы общие, но вот приложение, запущенное через один комп, не видится через другой - почему и как конкретно это лечить!? :)

Windows server 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что сессия подключения другая... тут по моему очевиден ответ.) Виндовс может запустить сколь угодно много копий любого приложения, присваивая каждому из них свой индивидуальный IDшник. При подключении вы входите в систему под ОДНИМ И ТЕМ ЖЕ логин/паролем, но ID сессии разные.

Соответственно у Вас в вашей учетке запущена софтина, только винда думает, что у другого пользователя. Через диспетчер задач в этом можно убедиться.

Comment: А как тогда получить доступ к приложению запущенному с другого компа!?

Comment: либо запретить несколько одновременных авторизаций, или к примеру использовать сторонний софт, к примеру радмин. + если мне не изменяет память, вопрос был - почему, а не почему и как это лечить:)

Comment: Вопрос переформулировал! Если не сложно обьясните как стандартными средствами запретить несколько одновременных авторизаций!?

Comment: ну раз пошли так... пуск->панель управления->администрирование->службы->Вторичный вход в систему. выключаем)) имя службы seclogon(если убивать через консоль)

Comment: Как то выглядит жестковато, вот так просто отключить службу и всё!?

Comment: вроде как да.

Comment: ну вроде как да) тогда каждый раз вы будете авторизовываться одним и тем же ID:)